# 'append' is undefined on HTMLDivElement object in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I have below line of code

```
var divElement= document.createElement( 'div' );
divElement.setAttribute( "id", "testId" );
element[ 0 ].append( divElement);
```

Where 'element' is $element from directive. So element[0] is an HTML div object.
Above code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE it gives 'append' is undefined and says 'Object doesn't support property or method 'append'.

Comment: Use `appendChild` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I may recommend you to use [`angular.element.append()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite) instead of [`ParentNode.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append). Otherwise, you may need to use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append#Polyfill) to support IE.

Answer (score 0):

The [`append` method](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-append) of the [`ParentNode` mixin](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-parentnode) is a relatively new addition; Internet Explorer is (at this point) quite an old browser.

In your case, since you're appending a single element (not HTML or multiple nodes), you can use [`appendChild`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-appendchild) (on the [`Node` interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-node)) instead:

```
element[ 0 ].appendChild( divElement);
// ----------------^^^^^
```

---

Side note: To set an element's `id`, you can use the reflected property rather than `setAttribute`:

```
divElement.id = "testId";
```